# According to Ellen White, will all nations become Christians?

Tags: prophecy, sabbath, seventh-day-adventists, sunday

I'm from Brazil (we speak Portuguese language) and with help of translating tools I've translated the following paragraphs to ask my question. The question is related to Ellen White prophecies.

> The time is not far distant when the test will come to **every soul**. The
> **observance of the false sabbath** will be **urged upon us**. The contest
> will be between the commandments of God and the commandments of men.
> Those who have yielded step by step to worldly demands and conformed
> to worldly customs will then yield to the powers that be, rather than
> subject themselves to derision, insult, threatened imprisonment, and
> death. At that time the gold will be separated from the dross. True
> godliness will be clearly distinguished from the appearance and tinsel
> of it. Many a star that we have admired for its brilliance will then
> go out in darkness. Those who have assumed the ornaments of the
> sanctuary, but are not clothed with Christ's righteousness, will then
> appear in the shame of their own nakedness. (Prophets and Kings, p. 181)

> 16, 17 (Daniel 3:1-18; see EGW on 1 John 2:18). History Will Be
> Repeated—History will be repeated. False religion will be exalted. The
> first day of the week, a common working day, possessing no sanctity
> whatever, will be set up as was the image at Babylon. **All nations** and
> tongues and peoples will be **commanded to worship this spurious**
> **sabbath**. This is Satan's plan to make of no account the day instituted
> by God, and given to the world as a memorial of creation.
>
> The decree enforcing the worship of this day is to go forth to all the
> world. In a limited degree, it has already gone forth. In several
> places the civil power is speaking with the voice of a dragon, just as
> the heathen king spoke to the Hebrew captives. (EGW SDA Bible Commentary, vol. 7, p. 976.8)

Then all nations will be Christian before this decree, because it is not possible for them to impose something that only makes sense to Christian without being Christian.

That means democracy all around the world and no more states of muslim and any other religion?

- No more North Korean dictators
- China will officially adopt Christianity
- No more muslim countries (today it is over 50)
- etc...

Another 2000 years to wait? Don't get me wrong, I believe in most prophecies of EGW, but it seems like will take time to see it happening.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Why do you say "another 2,000 years to wait"?  Is this based on your assumption that every country/nation will have to become Christian and therefore democratic?  It would be helpful if you could explain why you think this because nothing in the Bible suggests the entire world will have to become Christian before the return of Christ.

Comment: "The decree enforcing the worship of this day is to go forth to all the world". You should pay attention to what I already wrote. This implies government decree (such one would necessarily be Christian). You wrote "nothing in the Bible suggests the entire world will have to become Christian". I'm asking from the perspective of a Seventh Day Adventist. You have to believe that EGW is a prophet to answer my question properly. @Lesley

Comment: Yes, I understand that you seek answers from the perspective of Seventh Day Adventism.  Since I do not believe that EGW is a prophet, I won't be attempting to answer your question, but I am interested to find out what the "official" view is.

Answer (score 3):

Your quotations clearly state that Ellen G. White foretold a future time when *"observance of the **false** sabbath will be urged upon us."* Further, *"All nations and tongues and peoples will be commanded to worship this **spurious** sabbath. This is Satan's plan..."* I have put in bold two words that answer your question. Now, taking that as understood, I proceed from there.

Having some (but not all) the literature Ellen G. White authored, I do not recall her ever foretelling a time when all nations will become Christians. On the contrary, she repeats time without number the eventual demise of all nations that do not uphold the Seventh Day Adventist religion, but not only by insisting that the Fourth of the Ten Commandments be upheld. That is certainly the main one SDA adherents are known for promulgating, but keeping ***all*** of the Ten Commandments is deemed to be part of God's requirements.

A foundational teaching of Ellen G. White is that the most holy place in the temple of God was opened in heaven in 1844, and inside the ark was seen the two tablets of stone God had written the Ten Commandments upon. Here is what she says about that:

> "Within the holy of holies, in the sanctuary of heaven, the divine law
> is sacredly enshrined - the law that was spoken by God Himself amid
> the thunders of Sinai and written with His own finger on the tables of
> stone.
>
> The law of God in the sanctuary in heaven is the great original...
> Those who arrived at an understanding of this important point were
> thus led to see the sacred, unchanging character of the divine law...
> The law of God, being a revelation of his will, a transcript of his
> character, must forever endure... light was shining from that open door of the sanctuary in heaven, and ***the fourth commandment was show to be included in the law*** which is there enshrined." *The Great Controversy*, Ellen G.
> White, p.266-7, Advent Books (emphasis mine.)

A point of note here is that, in the view of the SDA, Catholicism continues to violate not only the law on God's Sabbath, but other laws, such as not having images etc. Thus they say Catholicism remains aligned with the beast of Revelation, having its mark. Making a demand for all people to observe a first-day-of-the-week sabbath would not mean genuine Christianity. As your quotes show, that is ***a false sabbath, one that Satan wants to be followed.***

The chapter goes on to explain Ellen G. White's interpretation of the beast, and its mark (Rev.14:9, 10), declaring Catholicism to be the instigator of observing the 'wrong' day, and that Protestants who go along with that day "is an homage they pay, in spite of themselves, to the authority of the [Catholic] Church." (She quotes here from a Catholic document; see p.275 *Ibid*.). This means that even when (as SDAs expect) Rome will turn around and declare the first day of the week to be the 'official Sabbath day' that the world must observe, all who fall into line with that will (in her words):

> "But when Sunday observance shall be forced by law, and the world
> shall be enlightened concerning the obligation of the true Sabbath,
> then whoever shall transgress the command of God, to obey a precept
> which has no higher authority than that of Rome, will thereby honour
> popery above God. He is paying homage to Rome and to the power which
> enforces the institution ordained of Rome. He is worshipping the beast
> and his image...
>
> In the issue of the contest all Christendom will be divided into two
> great classes - those who keep the commandments of God and the faith
> of Jesus, and those who worship the beast and his image and receive
> his mark. Although ***church and state will unite their power to
> compel "all***, both small and great, rich and poor, free and bond"
> (Revelation 13:16), to receive "the mark of the beast", yet the people
> of God will not receive it." (**Ibid**. p.276) Emphasis mine.

From this it might be seen that Ellen G. White was not thinking in terms of all nations becoming Christian, but of all who go by a legal decree issued by Rome and worldly governments to compel them to start observing the first day as a time of rest and worship, as receiving the deadly "mark of the beast". The SDAs claim not to be in that number, having the saving mark of Christ on them, as shown by this other SDA writer. Uriah Smith published his 700 page tome in 1908 and he agrees with Ellen G. White. Consider this tiny sample quote:

> "And in this we find still further evidence that ***Sunday keeping is
> the mark of the beast... The beast also has a seal, or mark, which is
> his sabbath***... Christendom will at last be divided into just two
> classes: to wit, those who are sealed with the seal of the living God
>
> - that is, have His mark, or keep His Sabbath - and those who are sealed with the mark of the beast - that is, have his mark, or keep
>   his sabbath.
>
> "...the reader may ask for some evidence that a person cannot be said
> to keep the commandments of God unless he does keep the seventh day."
> and proceeds to give SDA evidence. (*Daniel and the Revelation*, U.
> Smith, p.587-8, Stanborough Press, 1908 Emphasis mine.

So, the answer to your question is "No", because it will be a false, satanic sabbath being enjoined on all nations, said Ellen G. White. It will be a great deception Satan and his visible agents will enact, so that agreement with it just won't come into it. "Compulsion" will be the key word. If you think dictatorship is already at work in some countries, "You ain't seen nothin' yet," according to the SDA interpretation of things.

Comment: Excellent and thorough research. Well-informed reporting. Up-voted +1. A prime example of how the site functions.

Comment: If Sunday is not worshiped and there is only one rest there is no transgression, but for there to be transgression there is a need to worship the false Saturday (Sunday). If there is "worship" then there is an association with Christianity, as this movement comes from Catholicism and established Protestant churches (Christian denominations). In other words, once again it is difficult to understand how the state enacts laws with a Christian vision (even if mistaken) without being Christian. I liked your answer but I'll leave open for more answers. Thanks @Anne.